# How to know all the actions taken on postgres SQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way to know all the events occurred on a specific table without enabling postgres logs.

Just want to know weather the sequence of addition/deletion/ Modification.

Thanks

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you are looking for audit trail,if yes https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

Comment: @user3837299 welcome to SO, please make that comment an answer and explain a bit.

Comment: @jpmc26 I am trying to check a specific table to see the patter of events coming . i cannot open post gres logs because this is going to hit my system performance. So i want to track only one table.

Comment: @Nbajam2015 **Any** solution is going to incur a performance hit. How much of one you can tolerate is a *requirement* that's important to what solutions will work for you.

Comment: Well i am trying to get 3000 events ina  span of 3 -4 days. I dont thing that will cost

Answer (score 1):

For audit trail in postgres you have to write an function and call it in a trigger, please have a look at **wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger** , You will have to write a function stating that if an update or delete or insert is happening on a table it will trigger an action updating a audit table capturing required information such as ip address, query, old data, new data, timestamp of the action that has occured etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers (see [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)) to observe all changes, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON my_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_function();
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON my_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_function();
CREATE TRIGGER delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON my_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_function();
```

or do this with just one function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER universal_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE universal_function();
```

Comment: Lemme try this!! I ll get back